# Oralcle generate number column inline (single statement)

Tags: sql, oracle, sequences

I am working on **Oracle** and I am having difficulty on generating a column of a defined range (say, 2008 to 2011). I know there is a **sequences** method see [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php).

However, I want to have it inline so that my PHP can work with it smoothly.

I also know there is a rather ugly way of doing it; for instance

```
select 2008 yr from dual 
union 
select 2009 yr from dual
union 
select 2010 yr from dual
union 
select 2011 yr from dual
```

Is there a more dynamic way?

Thanks for your kind assistance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 2008 + level-1 yr
from dual connect by level <  5
```

Change constants as needed.

Comment: I was doing the fiddle but you answered first so: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/1632 ;) +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive query:

```
with dta(yr) as (
select 2008 from dual
union all
select yr+1 from dta where yr < 2011
)
select * from dta
```

and the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/1670)

Comment: Thanks, it works on fiddle. But Im not sure if it's version issue or not, the sql doesn't work on Oracle 9.

Comment: No recursive sql was introduced in Oracle 11. You'll have to use the heirarchical version that OldProgrammer provided.